# Where do I set the validatorURL flag to NULL in the swagger.json for my Swagger UI docs?

Tags: flask, swagger, swagger-ui

I created Swagger UI docs using Swagger Editor for my APIs which are hosted on a private AWS EC2 instance. The VM is private and Swagger isn't able to validate my URL and hence I'm getting this error on my Swagger UI webpage:

`{"schemaValidationMessages":[{"level":"error","message":"Can't read from file https://xx.xx.xxx.xx:9001/static/swagger.json"}]}`

I converted the YAML that got generated from Swagger Editor into *swagger.json* and used the `flask_swagger_ui` Python library to link the *swagger.json* with my API code. This *swagger.json* is the only Swagger-related file I have and I didn't use any .html or .config files. I realised if I set `ValidatorURL: null` then the abovementioned error will stop but where do I add that flag/parameter in the *swagger.json* (Swagger YAML design) file? Other resources mention adding `ValidatorURL: null` in the .html file but I don't have any such file. What do I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`validatorUrl` is a Swagger UI config option. In `flask_swagger_ui`, you can set this option as follows:

```py
swaggerui_blueprint = get_swaggerui_blueprint(
    SWAGGER_URL,
    API_URL,
    config={
        'validatorUrl': 'none'
    },
    ...
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! It worked and I don't see the error anymore.